# Is it possible to raise the voltage of a power source by lowering its current indefinitely (i.e. transformers)?

Tags: electricity, electric-current, voltage, electronics

Let's say you have a D battery. You wire it up to the primary of a step-up transformer, which you then in turn wire up to another step-up transformer,...etc. Is there a limit to how high the voltage can go? Can you arbitrarily lift it to quadrillions of volts? (Lowering the current, of course, to virtually zero) Or is there a limit?

Comment: The limits would be in the dielectric breakdown of the transformer materials. It gets very hard to produce DC voltages much higher than 10MV and we have basically given up on DC particle accelerators somewhere around that range. Higher particle energies (which is equivalent to what you are asking for) can be achieved by accelerating with AC fields. In effect, an accelerator like LHC is a giant transformer which produces an effective voltage of 14 trillion Volt, but you would have a hard time powering that with a battery. :-)

Comment: Are you asking for a *practical* limit (imposed by material properties, as indicated by CuriousOne), or for a *theoretical* limit?

Comment: @ACuriousMind Both, if you don't mind.

Comment: @CuriousOne Really? Strange, but normal hobbyists like me have created Tesla coils and other DIY projects with well over 70,000 volts of energy (transformed from a much lower voltage power source)

Comment: 70,000 V is a lot less than 10 MV (mega volts - $10^6$ V) which is 10,000,000 V. Note also you need to turn the DC into AC for it to be "transformed" - then rectified again at the high voltage end. This means your rectifier has to be able to withstand the voltage...

Comment: @CuriousOne My bad.

Comment: 70kV is a more or less trivial voltage, it gets tough beyond a couple hundred thousand Volt, after you have to start working with oil baths and $SF_6$.